# Fitting a nested experimental design in R

Tags: r, mixed-model, nested-data, lme4-nlme

I am analyzing experimental growth data where I have fixed effects A and B (two levels each), an interaction between them (AxB) and 5 culture replicates for each combination of A and B.  Numerical summary looks like this:

- Factor (**A**): 2 levels
- Factor (**B**): 2 levels
- Factor (**B**): 2 levels
- Level (**L**=AxB): 2x2=4 combinations
- Replicates (**R**): 5
- total n=20

from this experiment I have ~40-60 size measurements (continuous response **Y**) from each replicate (total n~1,200).  I am trying to fit a linear model to incorporate the fixed effects as well as the random effect of replicates within the experimental level.  After 4 hours of searching online, the model that seems most appropriate is:

```
fit<-lmer(Y~A+B+L+(1|L/R), data=my.data)
```

Am I thinking about this the right way?  Is **(1|L/R)** designating replicate variance **(R)** within the given level **(L)**?